# Composition of Characteristic Function / Fourier Transformation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

I have to prove that if $\Phi$ is a characteristic function, then $\psi(t)=e^{\lambda (\Phi (t) - 1)}$ is also a characteristic function.

I guess I'm supposed to use Bochner-Khinchin's theorem, showing that $\psi$ is a positive-semidefinite function, but I'm not sure how.

Also, $\psi(t)=h(\Phi (t))$ where $h(x)=e^{\lambda(x-1)}$ and $h$ is continuous.
Is there an assertion about the composition of characteristic functions with continuous or convex functions?

Comment: If $\Phi$ is absolutely continuous so it is $\psi$, that is pretty trivial. Assuming that $\Phi$ has a Taylor series at the origin with positive coefficient, can you prove that $\psi$ has the same property?

Answer (score 2):

Recall two statements; the first one is obvious from the very definiton of positive definiteness:

> **Lemma 1:** Let $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ be positive definite functions and $\lambda \geq 0$ a constant. Then $\lambda \Phi_1$ and $\Phi_1+\Phi_2$ are positive definite functions.
>
> **Lemma 2:** For any characteristic function $\Phi$ and any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\Phi^n$ is a characteristic function; in particular $\Phi^n$ is positive definite.

*Proof of Lemma 2:* Since $\Phi$ is a characteristic function, there exists a random variable $X$ such that $\Phi(t) = \mathbb{E}e^{i tX}$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that there exists an independent random variable $Y$ such that $Y \sim X$ (otherwise we enlarge the probability space using a product construction). Then

$$\mathbb{E}e^{i t (X+Y)} = \mathbb{E}e^{i t X} \mathbb{E}e^{i t Y} = \Phi(t)^2$$

which shows that $\Phi^2$ is a characteristic function. By induction, we find that $\Phi^n$ is a characteristic function for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$; hence, by Bochner's theorem, positive definite. This finishes the proof.

Now use these two statements to prove the assertion:

1. Prove that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $$\phi_n(t) := \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} (\lambda \Phi(t))^k$$ is positive definite.
2. Using that the pointwise limit of positive definite functions is positive definite (provided the limit exists), show that $\phi(t) = e^{\lambda \Phi(t)}$ is positive definite.
3. Applying Bochner's theorem conclude that $\psi(t)=e^{\lambda (\Phi(t)-1)}$ is a characteristic function.

Comment: How do we know that $e^{\lambda (\Phi(t)-1)}$ is positive definite?

Comment: @Hendrra Well, I gave some hints how to show this (see the very end of my answer), didn't I? Could you be please more precise?

Comment: You showed in the second point that the function $\phi(t) = e^{\lambda \Phi(t)}$ is positive definite. Using the pointwise limit and your previous observations. That's really well explained. However in the third point you claim that $\psi(t)$ is a characteristic function thus is positive definite too. It's not obvious for me. Does the subtraction of one change nothing?

Comment: @Hendrra If $f$ is a positive definite function, then $c \cdot f$ is a positive definite function for any constant $c>0$; you can verify this easily from the very definition of positive definiteness. Since $\psi(t) = e^{-\lambda} \varphi(t)$ this yields immediately that $\psi$ is positive definite... and then we can apply Bochner's theorem. (A side remark: The subtraction of one doesn't change anything about the positive definiteness, but it changes the scaling of the function. Note that a characteristic function needs to take the value $1$ at $t=0$.

Comment: .. as a consequence, $\varphi$ is **not** a characteristic function but $\psi$ is.)

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand it. I appreciate your time and help :)

Comment: @Hendrra You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{X_i, i\ge 1\}$ be i.i.d. rvs with common characteristic function $\Phi(t)$ and $Y$ be a independent Poisson distributed r.v with $E(Y)=\lambda$, then the characteristic function of $Z=\sum\limits_{i=1}^Y X_i$ is the following, 
$$ E[e^{itZ}]=E[E[e^{it\sum_{i=1}^YX_i}\mid Y]]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty E[e^{it\sum_{i=1}^kX_i}]P(Y=k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty[\Phi(t)]^k\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda} =  e^{\lambda(\Phi(t)-1)}.$$